# Is it possible to have two updatestatebykey() in one spark streaming application?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark streaming and just know the `updateStatebyKey()` function. I want to ask whether it's possible to have 2 `updatestatebykey()` function in one application?

I only use one streaming, but want to process it in different way and need to keep each state.

If possible can you explain it a little, because from what I know, from 1 streaming context, we can only use 1 checkpoint directory?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple `updateStateByKey` calls for the same DAG. But, note that Spark Streaming is largely deprecated and isn't very efficient. I'd recommend looking at Structured Streaming instead which has `mapGroupsWithState`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I use multiple `updateStateByKey` with different function, it can make a state of each id become wrong, isn't it? because I want to detect some patterns from the same data, so I need to keep state for each pattern. Can you explain a little about how to do it the right way?
And for you suggestion, I will take a look a it. Thank you.

Comment: I actually blogged about it a while back, see if that post can help you: https://blog.yuvalitzchakov.com/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-apache-spark/

Comment: Okay, thank you I get an idea after reading that.